# Example of $E_0(K)$ which satisfies $[E(K):E_0(K)]＝2$

Tags: arithmetic, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over local field $K$ which has good reduction. $E(K)/E_0(K)$ is known to be finite .

Now I'm looking for an example of $E_0(K)$ which satisfies $[E(K):E_0(K)]＝2$.

Let $K＝\Bbb Q_p$, I tried some elliptic curve like $E:y^2＝x^3＋3$ over $\Bbb Q_3$, $E(\Bbb Q_3)＝4$,but I couldn't list the points of $E_0(\Bbb Q_3)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $E(\mathbb{Q}_3) = 4$. The order shouldn't be that, these shouldn't even countable sets, so listing points is rather doomed to failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to construct such examples. By a Theorem of Kodaira-Neron (Silverman, Theorem VII.6.1) if $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $E$ has split multiplicative reduction then the Tamagawa number $[E(K) : E_0(K)]$ is equal to the valuation of the discriminant (in specific cases you can just follow Tate's algorithm to verify).

Just looking through the [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org) one can find examples pretty quickly. For example the curve with Cremona Label $21a2$
$$E : y^2 + xy = x^3 - 49x - 136.$$

has split multiplicative reduction at $3$ and discriminant $3^2 \cdot 7^4$.

Comment: What is the point of $E_0(K)$?

Comment: Well, you want to define a filtration of $E(K)$ right, this is the obvious first part of it. The simplest application is showing that $E(K)$ has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K$ and so you immediately deduce that the torsion subgroup is finite.